# Connection pool sharing between different python scripts

Tags: python, redis, psycopg2, connection-pooling

I would like to share a pool of connections between several python scripts. I have a list of jsons like.

```
{
 'name': 'Task 1',
 'command': 'python',
 'args': ['/home/admin/task1.py','5']
}
{
 'name': 'Task 2',
 'command': 'env/bin/python',
 'args': ['/home/admin/task2.py','8']
}
```

Which I sent to a redis queue.

Now is it possible to share the connection pool between task1.py and task2.py?

For example:

```py
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.pool
import configparser

class PostgresConnection:
    def __init__(self, config_file='database_config.ini'):
        # Initialize the PostgresConnection class
        self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.config.read(config_file)  # Read the configuration file
        self.connection_pool = None  # Connection pool object for managing connections

    def connect(self):
        try:
            # Get the connection parameters from the configuration file
            connection_params = {
                'host': self.config.get('postgresql', 'host'),
                'port': self.config.get('postgresql', 'port'),
                'database': self.config.get('postgresql', 'database'),
                'user': self.config.get('postgresql', 'user'),
                'password': self.config.get('postgresql', 'password')
            }
            # Create a threaded connection pool with 1 minimum and 50 maximum connections
            self.connection_pool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(1, 50, **connection_params)
        except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
            pass

    def disconnect(self):
        if self.connection_pool:
            self.connection_pool.closeall()  # Close all connections in the connection pool

    def execute_query(self, query, params=None):
        try:
            with self.connection_pool.getconn() as connection:
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.execute(query, params)  # Execute the query with optional parameters
                    connection.commit()  # Commit the transaction
                    return cursor.fetchall()  # Return the query results
        except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
            return None
        finally:
            self.connection_pool.putconn(connection)  # Release the connection back to the pool
```

Where **task1.py** and **task2.py** are like:

```py
from databse import PostgresConnection

c = PostgresConnection()
c.connect()

# do things

c.disconnect()
```

I read a lot about `psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool` but in the example I made, the pool is initialized twice if I call the PostgresConnection class in two scripts.

Is there any way to do this? I also read about singleton but it seems to be not a good idea. On the other hand I didn't get "Module-level connection pool" and "Passing the connection pool as an argument" approach.

Comment: No you can't do this, the `pool` in `psycopg2` is restricted to the module you call it in. So this `from database import PostgresConnection` is going to create a new pool in each script. You either have to: 1) Put all the code in one module or 2) Use an external pooler like [PgBouncer](http://www.pgbouncer.org/) or [Pgpool-II](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/intro-whatis.html) or equivalent.

Comment: not even with a singleton so that there is a single instance of the pool?

Comment: You will need to define that further in your question.